# django admin. Create parent with child in same form

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, django-admin

I have two classes in my model.py

```
class User(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  phone = models.CharField()
  # Other common fields

class Customer(User):
  payment = models.CharField()
  user__id = models.OneToOneField('User', db_column='id', primary_key=True)

class Company(User):
  address = models.CharField()
  user_id = models.OneToOneField('User', db_column='id', primary_key=True)
```

When I use the admin of Customer/Company it includes all User fields, that is perfect for me. But this form of Customer/Company also includes a dropdown list with the foreign key of an User, and I don't want to create the User first and then the Customer/Company object. I want that when I fill the Customer/Company form (with User fields) I should create the User object too.

Is there a way to solve this without create a User instance prior the Customer/Company instance?

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492424/django-admin-foreign-key-field-data-add) might be the answer you are looking for. You will have to customize the admin in `admin.py` where you register your models.

Comment: normally you'd want to the opposite: create a linked model (B) automatically when the model it links to is created (A). BTW: are you sure you need model B to inherit from model A? Do you know what it entails at the DB level?

Comment: @Pynchia For me, sounds logic. Actually I have three models. User, Customer and Company. Customer and Company are subclasses of User, so it is logic that I want a form for Company (with Company+User fields) and another for Customer (with Customer+User), isn't?

Comment: I think you may want to rethink your models. I don't think it makes sense for a Company to be a User. Perhaps the Company *has* a User, like an admin.

Comment: @Brobin the model User is only common data for a Company and also for a Customer

Comment: If it extends `User`, it shouldn't need a child `User` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the last comment... Could you explain more?

Comment: Your `Company` and `Customer` objects both extend and have an instance of `User` which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Wow, maybe I am too weird in thinking problems :/ ... For me it was logic, using the advantages of inheritance of models, I created a class with common data among the users of my app (`Users` model), and then I created two subclasses for specific information (`Customer` and `Company` models). 

I just wanted that the creation of a subclass (`Customer` or `Company`) occurred at the same form that its parent, so I wouldn't need to do two-steps process... Thanks anyway @Brobin

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding an inline in your model registration in `admin.py`.

```
class AInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = A

class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AInline]

admin.register(A)
admin.register(B, BAdmin)
```

[Django inline model admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be the inverse? Because I am getting this error:

`'app_name.A' has no ForeignKey to 'app_name.B'`.

Comment: I'm not sure if the code is exactly correct as I don't have your code to test it, but this is the type of thing you need to do.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it should be the inverse.

Comment: Anyway I tried in the inverse but it throwed me fields of `A` repeated... Because when I create the inheritance I already have the `A` fields in my `B` form. The problem is that I want to create `B` and `A` at once

Comment: Hmm, so `B` inherits `A` and also has an `A`?

Comment: Why do you need 2 classes? Couldn't `B` simply have a relationship with another `B`?

Comment: Yes. I can create an `A` with its form and I can create a `B` with its form, but the problem is that when I create `B` I need to say which `A` use, and for me it should be created in the same moment of `B` because I am filling `A` fields in `B` form