# How to auto increment a model field in django admin form by having add another on the side?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, field

I have this model:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='Admin')    
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()

    # todo support for tags
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='travel') #todo
    date_created = models.DateField()
```

Now in tags field, I want to give multiple strings like #tips, #travel, etc on the same field. What I want is there should be like an add or increment tag, which when I click will show another tag field appears on the admin form and the user can adder another tag.

My backend is not on the regular HTML page. I have customized the default Django admin page for the backend using the material package. That is I cant use button tag and all.

How can I achieve this?? **I have an image attached which explains better.**

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64yl9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create another model called `Tag` and connect it to your `BlogPost` like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
     text = models.CharField(max_length=244, default='travel')
     blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tags')
```

Then if you want to acces tags of a certain post in a view you would use:

```
blog_post = BlogPost.objects.get(pk=pk) # query the blog post you want the tags to
tags = blog_post.tags.all() # get the tags
```

Then simply add a form to each blog post where you would add a tag and save it to the related post. I'm not sure how you would do it an an admin interface though.

Comment: I can another model and make a foreign key with the parent model, but how to make this appear in Django admin UI??

Comment: Check out this answer by Darioush: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492424/django-admin-foreign-key-field-data-add