# Many-to-many relationships in Django Admin

Tags: django, admin

**models:**

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Cars(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    details = models.ManyToManyField(Detail)
```

So, every car has a many details - wheels, engine, etc. How to do this: in Django Admin situated Cars menu, in that menu we have a many lines of details (like in [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/)).
In **admin** I use:

```
class DetailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Detail
    extra = 6
class CarsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DetailInline]
```

But it has error: **Detail has no ForeignKey to Cars**. How to fix it?

Comment: There's something ambiguous in you models: is it possible to reuse the same detail for many cars? If yes, you should not use inlines because when modifying a detail for a car it will change the detail for all the cars that use it. If no, the solution is to use a ForeignKey in the Detail model pointing to the Car model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does not natively let you add a reverse inline.
i.e. You can have the Detail page contain an inline admin of all the Cars that contain a ForeignKey to that particular Detail. However, the reverse is not natively possible.

There is a workaround though wherein you have to override the admin template a bit. There is a previous SO question about this here: [Inline-like solution for Django Admin where Admin contains ForeignKey to other model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419248/inline-like-solution-for-django-admin-where-admin-contains-foreignkey-to-other-m)