# Trouble with Django Admin Inlines using Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
#models.py
class BasePost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    prompt = HTMLField()
    assets = MultiFileField(upload_to="assets/%Y/%m", blank=True)


class Activity(OrderedModel):
    prompt = models.ForeignKey(BasePost, related_name="prompts+")
    feature1 = models.ForeignKey(BasePost, related_name="feature+")
    feature2 = models.ForeignKey(BasePost, related_name="feature1+")

#admin.py
class BasePostInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BasePost

class ActivityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ BasePostInline, ]

admin.site.register(Activity, ActivityAdmin)
```

Essentially: Prompt, feature1, feature2 are all objects of type BasePost.  BasePost has title, content, assets.

In the admin for Activity I can't figure out how to get title, content and asset fields to show up for each.  Instead I'm just seeing dropdowns to select existing "BasePosts".

I tried using inlines but just couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have everything set backwards - You register your base class and set the Activity class as it's inline. Try this:

```
#admin.py
class ActivityInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Activity

class BasePostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ ActivityInline, ]

admin.site.register(BasePost, BasePostAdmin)
```

UPDATE:

Duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419248/inline-like-solution-for-django-admin-where-admin-contains-foreignkey-to-other-m) then:

Comment: I want the opposite though.  So that an activity has a prompt, feature1, feature2 all of the format of (title, content, assets) Essentially, I'm trying to find a shortcut for this: [link]http://pastebin.com/HVWuy9Kz

So that I don't need to create custom template code for each prompt, feature1, feature2 which are all identical in structure, just named differently.